# SSN issue in SIEBEL

Tags: regex

I am working on  siebel CRM. I have space issues in my regex.

I have SSN numbers in these formats

```
123 456 789
123-456-789
123 45 6789
```

I need to dispaly my SSN Like `XXX-XX-4567`. My regex looks like

```
([\s.:])(?!000)(?!666)(?!9[0-9][0-9])\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4})([\s.:]) |
([\s.:])(?!000)(?!666)(?!9[0-9][0-9])\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{3})([\s.:]).
```

How can I remove all blank spaces in the above expression and display the format as i mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are syntax errors in your RegEx. There are a couple of unmatched brackets, at `(?!0000)\d{4})` on the first section, the last bracket is unmatched.

I think I've managed to write the regex you're looking for, but a bit shorter than the one you were using:

```
([\s.:])((?!000)(?!666)(?!9[0-9]{2})\d{3})[- ]?((?!00)\d{2,3})[- ]?((?!00)\d{3,4})([\s.:])
```

This will match the following strings:

```
123-12-1234
123 456 789
123-456-789
123 45 6789
```

But will not match the following:

```
666-45-1234
abc-12-1232
123-00-1233
123-224-0011
123 224 0000
```

There are several capture groups here:

1. Matches any character (you may want to change this).
2. Matches the first three digit number.
3. Matches the second, two or three digit number.
4. Matches the third, three or four digit number.
5. Matches any character (you may want to change this).

You should be able to reconstruct the SSN in the format you need with the result of this RegEx.